# Notation in Advances in Finance ML for time interval

Tags: time-series, tick-data, self-study

I was reading Prof. Lopez book Advances in Finance ML and he uses a notation I could not understand. In 4.2 (Overlapping Outcomes) he says:

> In Chapter 3 we assigned a label $y_i$ to an observed feature $X_i$, where $y_i$ was a function of price bars that occurred over an interval $[t_{i, 0}, t_{i, 1}]$. When $t_{i, 1} > t_{j, 0}$ and $i < j$, then $y_i$ and $y_j$ will both depend on a common return , that is, the return over the interval $[t_{j, 0}, min\{t_{i, 1}, t_{j, 1}\}]$.

In chapter 3.2 (The Fixed-Time Horizon Method) he writes:

> Consider a features matrix $X$ with $I$ rows, $\{X_i\}_{i = 1, …, I}$, drawn from some bars with index $t = 1, …, T$, where $I ≤ T$. Chapter 2, Section 2.5 discussed sampling methods that produce the set of features $\{X_i\}_{i = 1, …, I}$. An observation $X_i$ is assigned a label $y_i ∈ \{ − 1, 0, 1\}$,
> $\begin{equation}
>   y_i =
>     \begin{cases}
>       -1 & \text{if $r_{t_{i,0},t_{i,0}+h} < -\tau$}\\
>       0 & \text{if $|r_{t_{i,0},t_{i,0}+h}| \le \tau$}\\
>       1 & \text{if $r_{t_{i,0},t_{i,0}+h} > \tau$}\\
>     \end{cases}       
> \end{equation}$
> where $\tau$ is a pre-defined constant threshold, $t_{i, 0}$ is the index of the bar immediately after $X_i$ takes place, $t_{i, 0} + h$ is the index of the $h$-th bar after $t_{i, 0}$, and $r_{t_{i,0},t_{i,0}+h}$ is the price return over a bar horizon $h$.

I have the following question and would appreciate if somebody could help me out:

1. Is the notation in the book $t_{i,0}+h$ correct or is the authors intention $t_{i,0+h}$? If it is correct and $t_{i,0}$ is the index of the bar after $X_i$ takes place (as stated in the text) then what is $t_{i,1}$ stands for?
2. How can $t_{i, 1} > t_{j, 0}$ and at the same time $i < j$? Can somebody give an example for this?